# Is there a test suite for HTML/JavaScript canvas element?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, canvas

I'm developing an alternate backend for the canvas interface.  I started setting up test cases, and then it occurred to me that there may already by a set of tests, but google isn't forthcoming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://philip.html5.org/tests/canvas/suite/tests/

Comment: Looks promising; it will take a bit to modify it, but the code generation technique ought to make this fairly doable.